# Need to Transfer Files from One Linux Machine to Other Linux Machine via SFTP

Tags: linux, shell

I have created a very small script below which i want help me to move files from one server to other server periodically via cronjob.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='1.1.1.1'
FILE='EndpointUsage*.*'
PASS='password#'

sftp kingadmin@$HOST
password $PASS <<END_SCRIPT
binary
lcd /var/tmp/
mput $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Problem i am facing.

1) I need this script to give the password automatically, i do not want to give password manually whenever this script run. Currently when i ran the commands its asking for password as below.

```
LA:/var/tmp # ./portmove.sh
kingadmin@1.1.1.1's password:
```

2) I want to send the files to particular directory on remote server. Can you please help how to put the locations in the script so that my script can send the files to particular directory let say in every 10 minutes(which i can configure in cronjob)

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: #Ericj Can you please advise how can i use. However both the system in same network and behind the firewall, so i do not think there could be any problem?

Comment: @Ericj Thanks..I just saw it...however i still think i would like to go with my original plan to give the login and password. Can you please help me on that?

Comment: Dear All,Thanks i was able to fix the problem...

Comment: posting to the wrong site - this belongs on superuser

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a password, consider using a [public/private key pair](https://askleo.com/how_can_i_automate_an_sftp_transfer_between_two_servers/).

You can then [specify the key file](https://superuser.com/questions/483593/how-do-i-use-my-keyfile-to-sftp-transfer-data-from-one-server-to-another) instead of a password.

Comment: yes, storing a password in clear text is always risky on a system.

Comment: Can you please advise how can i use. 

However both the system in same network and behind the firewall, so i do not think there could be any problem?

Comment: The first link explains how to set it up.  Being on the same network only makes it easier.